# When to use/not use prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

- When should I use prepared statements? For *any* sort of query or just
  specific kinds?
- Should I be using prepared statements for SELECTING, or INSERTING, both, etc?
- When should I not use them?

Thanks.

Comment: use prepared statement when you have inputs from the user that will be saved or does something in the database.

Comment: @491243: Not just inputs from the user, any sort of "parameter", it could also come from a file or a different program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepared statements should be used for queries containing **parameters**. Otherwise, they are a waste of resources.

Example:

```
$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `table`"); //No need for preparing here, no parameters.
```

However

```
$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = :id"); //Prepare.
```

Comment: So if there are no parameters, just use a regular query like `$result = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT * FROM table");`?

Comment: Correct. Otherwise, you're wasting your resources for nothing. The reason some people will tell you to *always* prepare, is because many noobs don't know how and when to use each time, so it's better to prepare all than prepare none. Once you know your bearings though, these types of queries are the ones you don't prepare.

Comment: Just a general question, why should prepared statements be used when selecting things from the database? How come they're not just used for inserting?

Comment: Read up on SQL injection for more information. I can inject to select statements too.

Comment: The caveat of "you're wasting your resources for nothing" is probably irrelevant unless you're going to measure that the wasted resources are worth worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

> When should I use prepared statements? For any sort of query or just specific kinds?

For any sort preferably. Especially if you have a dedicated function or class for running queries. In such a case there should be just single method for running all the queries, no matter if they have dynamical parts or not.
Not to mention that all-static a query like "SELECT * FROM table" is a rare thing outside of sandbox.

> Should I be using prepared statements for SELECTING, or INSERTING, both, etc?

**Doesn't matter.** The idea is to represent **every dynamical value** in the query **with placeholder**. the query type absolutely doesn't matter.

> When should I not use them?

This question is quite similar to the first one. You would do yourself a mighty favor if use prepared statements all the way.

Answer (score -1):

You should use prepared statements and parametrized queries whenever you are going to be using data that comes from anywhere outside of your program.  That includes *any* interactions with the database, whether a INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE, or even a SELECT.

If you build SQL statements using data from the outside, you are in danger.

Comment: A grave delusion, this one. 1. Read something on second order injection. 2. Consider `Scarlett O'Hara` hardcoded in the very inside of your precious program.

Comment: Not delusional. I was only discussing the security aspects.  I'm trying to keep things simple.  Rather than being condescending and snarky at me, would you be willing to contribute some text and explanation about second order injection to http://bobby-tables.com/ ?  The source is at https://github.com/petdance/bobby-tables

Comment: That's exactly what I am talking about - security aspects. I am not being snarky to anyone personally, it's only answer text only I am arguing with. It's impersonal. Anyway, with all the honesty I don't understand why a developer should separate his data on "safe" and "unsafe". Why not to treat it it all the same way? Isn't it just simpler way? What if there are two developers, each working on their own part of program? How should they share that information on data source?

Comment: I agree, and your points are some that I think bobby-tables.com would benefit from.  Would you please be willing to contribute?  Either send a pull request with updated text, or open an issue and paste text in there and I'll integrate it into the site.